# Automatic save() for Nested Objects in PLAY! JPA

Tags: java, database, jpa, playframework, nested

I have a Play!Framework application with the following structure:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model{

    public User(String name, String email) {
        UserConfig userConfig = new UserConfig(this);
        userConfig.save();
    }
}

@Entity
public class UserConfig extends Model{

    @ManyToOne
    public User user;

    public UserOptions(User user) {
        this.user = user;
}
```

I create an instance of User through CRUD's admin page (CRUD module for Play! framework).

I thought that CRUD will automatically create the instance of UserConfig, but it doesn't.

What should I do to make CRUD save the nested entity?

Comment: @Evgeny I've tried to add CascadeType.ALL to my annotation, but it still doesn't work. When I create an Instance of User - this instance is correctly saved to the database, but default UserConfig, related to this User, doesn't appear in DB. I'm completly confused.

Answer (score 2):

Use CascadeType attribute of ManyToMany or ManyToOne annotation. E.g. @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL).

---

More about the CascadeType here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html